# How can I define state parameters in Aurelia router

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia and in the router configuration, I want to define state parameter and to navigate to that state when I click to the generated link by the router. I could not find any reference and a question about this

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you provide more information about your question?

Comment: export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: ['','user'], name: 'user', moduleId: 'users/user', params:"id" nav: true, title:'User' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
The part I am asking is how to define the "params" for a state

Comment: could you provide a concrete example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question...

Let's suppose you want to create an "edit" route. This route would be parametrized with an "id". Then, you should use a symbol, like `:id`, to represent the parameter. Like this:

```
export class App { 
     configureRouter(config, router) { 
         config.title = 'Aurelia'; 
         config.map([ 
             { route: ['','user'], name: 'user', moduleId: 'users/user', params:"id" nav: true, title:'User' } 
             //route with param
             { route: 'user/:id, name: 'userEdit', moduleId: 'users/edit', nav: false, title:'Edit User' }
         ]); 

         this.router = router; 
     } 
}
```

Hope it helps!